# Plot code with syntax highlighting in Python / matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, syntax-highlighting

I want to plot in an image a provided bit of code with the appropriate syntax highlighting. If possible, this should be doable in Python's matplotlib, but I am open to any solution I can reasonably ducktape into a Python script.

I thought this to be a banal question, but I haven't found a solution in a couple of days of desperate googling.

I went as far as to get LaTeX and minted running in [`matplotlib's annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html), but the damned thing does not colour the code correctly.

I hope there is some easier solution I haven't thought about.

Comment: You have to be more specific. There are plenty of libraries for unit tasks - syntax highlighting of texts, rendering colored texts to an image and plotting images. I don't expect there exists a ready-made simple solution for your problem.

Comment: I thought making images with properly highlighted code was a common task, but as you suggested, I have only found complex solutions. E.g., I could generate the HTML from Markdown, use [pypettier](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer) plus [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) to render the page, print it as a PDF, convert the PDF to an image, and load the image with matplotlib. But it feels like a crazy gimmick, and I need this to run thousands of times.

If there is no easy solution, I could reasonably spend time developing an open-source one.

Comment: You need to research more and ask a specific question, here in SO. That said, [Pygments](https://pygments.org/docs/formatters/#ImageFormatter) supports to output an image file.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti You might want to get tokens using Python3Lexer and get corresponding colors from TerminalFormatter of [Pygments](https://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/). I tried this, but couldn't parse a string which contains color information bundled with the code that needs to be highlighted.